# Core Plot - set zoom level to show only part of graph

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I'm having this Plot:

[image: Coreplot 1]

Every tick on the X-axis represents a day in the calendar. But as you can see, the date is very hard to read so I would like to set the the zoom level to show only 7 days instead of 11 (like right now). Please see screenshot below:

[image]

But it's important to have more data available, so users can scroll to the left and there will still be dates shown.

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the xRange and globallXRange properties to get work.

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange 
                    plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) 
                    length:CPDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(10)];

[plotSpace setGlobalXRange:[CPTPlotRange 
                    plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) 
                    length:CPDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(50)]];
```

Pass location and length values correctly.

Comment: Thanks. This absolutely worked. What does the second line actually do?  I have tried both of them and I don't see any effect of the `setGlobalXRange`-thing.

Comment: globalXRange property defines the maximum range that can be scrolled along X axis direction. xRange simply tells the maximum X range that can be shown in view. Try changing the values of these properties.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. And is there some way of setting a maximum zoom level? I don't want users to be able to zoom out to see more than 10 dates, they should be able to see all of the dates only by scrolling.

Comment: Well I think you have to make length of xRange to 5 (or some thing less than 10) and length of globalXRange to 10.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it... but thanks anyway. I had to use the `shouldScaleBy`-delegate method of plotSpaceDelegate. Setting the globalXRange to 10 would also disallow any scrolling beyond this range.