# limit core-plot min/max zoom

Tags: zooming, limit, core-plot

I try to limit core-plot zoom between 2 value, more or less my code work, but sometime it don't work properly, this is the code:

```
- (void) handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

        if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            scale = [gestureRecognizer scale];

        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

            CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

            lenghtX = [self getRoundedValue:max_X - min_X];
            lenghtY = [self getRoundedValue:max_Y - min_Y];


            if (lenghtX <= 100 && lenghtX >= 2) {

                double stepScale = lenghtX / 10;

                if ([gestureRecognizer scale] < scale) {

                    min_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.minLimitDouble - stepScale];
                    max_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.maxLimitDouble + stepScale];
                    min_Y = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.yRange.minLimitDouble - stepScale];
                    max_Y = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.yRange.maxLimitDouble + stepScale];
                }
                else {

                    min_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.minLimitDouble + stepScale];
                    max_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.maxLimitDouble - stepScale];
                    min_Y = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.yRange.minLimitDouble + stepScale];
                    max_Y = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.yRange.maxLimitDouble - stepScale];
                }
            }
            else {

                if (lenghtX > 100) {

                    double rest = [self getRoundedValue:(lenghtX - 100)/2];

                    min_X = [self getRoundedValue:min_X + rest];
                    max_X = [self getRoundedValue:max_X - rest];
                    min_Y = [self getRoundedValue:min_Y + rest];
                    max_Y = [self getRoundedValue:max_Y - rest];

                    NSLog(@"Lenght:%f Rest: %f",lenghtX,rest);

                }
                else if (lenghtX < 2) {

                    double rest = [self getRoundedValue:(2 - lenghtX)/2];

                    min_X = [self getRoundedValue:min_X - rest];
                    max_X = [self getRoundedValue:max_X + rest];
                    min_Y = [self getRoundedValue:min_Y - rest];
                    max_Y = [self getRoundedValue:max_Y + rest];

                    NSLog(@"Lenght:%f Rest: %f",lenghtX,rest);

                }
            }

            lenghtX = [self getRoundedValue:max_X - min_X];
            lenghtY = [self getRoundedValue:max_Y - min_Y];

             NSLog(@"Lenght: %f",lenghtX);

            plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(min_X) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(lenghtX)];
            plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(min_Y) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(lenghtY)];

            scale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
        }
        else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

            if (lenghtX <= 100 && lenghtX >= 2) {

                CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)self.graph.defaultPlotSpace;

                min_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.minLimitDouble];
                max_X = [self getRoundedValue:plotSpace.xRange.maxLimitDouble];

                step_punto = (max_X-min_X)/numero_punti;

                [self get_N_Value:numero_punti  from:min_X toMax:max_X];
            }
        }
    }

- (double) getRoundedValue:(double) value {
    double roundedValue = round(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
    return roundedValue;
}
```

In this code I check the length of visible x, if is >100 or <2 I set it 2 or 100, the problem is that not always the final value is inside this renege. The second problem is that when I zoom to the limit (for example when I zoom in) I want to block the zoom while now in the proximity of the limit there is a little zoom out and then a little zoom in (repeated).

How can I improve the code?

Comment: I'm assuming you added your own gesture recognizer to the hosting view. Did you disable the one provided by Core Plot (`allowsPinchScaling = NO`) to eliminate conflicts?

Comment: Yes!I have disabled the core plot pinch!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer if-else statement that begins with `if (lenghtX <= 100 && lenghtX >= 2)`. Always compute the scaled ranges and then check the length and adjust as necessary to bring it back in the 2-100 range.

Comment: at the end, I re-write all code, I find a better way for handle the end of zoom, I don't use pinch gesture but core-plot gesture, I limit the zoom out with xglobalrange, but I don't know I can I limit the zoom in, can I give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the accepted answer here:
[Core Plot - set zoom level to show only part of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609105/core-plot-set-zoom-level-to-show-only-part-of-graph)

This is using global X and Y range setting. Which works perfectly for me.

There is also a mention in the comments for using the CPTPlotSpaceDelegate's method:

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint;
```

Which would allow you to maintain a maximum zoom level. Note that minimum zoom level is actually handled by setting global X and Y ranges.